# DAX expression to isolate 2 columns from a table and filter the result table based on another column

Tags: t-sql, powerbi, dax

How can I convert the following query expression into a **DAX expression**:

```
SELECT Column3, Column2 FROM table2 WHERE Column4 < 450
```

Comment: do you want sum of Column3 and Column2?

Comment: No, I need to show columns 2 and 3 where the values in column 4 are greater than 450.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Modelling tab in Power BI, click on **New Table** and use the below expression:

```
 New Table =
   CALCULATETABLE (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'table2',
        "New Column 2", 'table2'[Column2],
        "New Column 3", 'table2'[Column3]
    ),
    'table2'[Column4] < 450
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with a `FILTER`

```
New Table =
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    FILTER ( 'table2', 'table2'[Column4] < 450 ),
    "New Column 2", 'table2'[Column2],
    "New Column 3", 'table2'[Column3]
)
```